# SQLAlchemy Inserts dont get Saved

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I Am trying to add some Rows to My Table with SQLAlchemy to my local SQLLite File. However the Rows dont get saved. I dont get any Primary Key Errors and i am also commiting my Inserts/Session.

What's really confusing me is that my Code works fine(My Inserts are Saved), when i am changing my Engine to Connect to a local postgresql-Server. I Am Calling the add_values Function from an other File.

```
def add_values(offers):
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///mydb.db",echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
with Session.begin() as session:
    list_of_offers =[]
    for ele in offers:
        offer = Offer(ele.id,ele.asin,ele.price,ele.currency,ele.condition,ele.seller,ele.datetime,ele.buyboxWinner,ele.numberOfSellers)
        list_of_offers.append(offer)
    session.add_all(list_of_offers)
    session.commit()
```

I Tryed to Change my Database to postgresql-Server.

Comment: you are using a relative path to your engine, can you check from the path wherever you are calling `add_values` if `mydb.db` is created there?